# Installing GitLab CI Runner on Raspberry Pi 2 (Raspbian)

Tags: ruby, gitlab, raspberry-pi2

I want to install the GitLab Runner for CI on my RPI 2 machine running Raspbian.

There is no armhf package available or mentioned on the official page: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab-runner/blob/master/doc/install/README.md

and I could not find one on the net.

---

I've tried building it from source but it failed to `make` ruby 2.1.5

Tried to install it as per the follwing guide:

http://qiita.com/honeniq/items/b5c767f947725280662e

but it fails:

```
Installing ruby-2.1.5...

BUILD FAILED (Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 using ruby-build 20150519-11-g6f1ed3d)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20150616110149.29126
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20150616110149.29126.log

Last 10 log lines:
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'srcs'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20150616110149.29126/ruby-2.1.5'
generating transdb.h
linking static-library libruby-static.a
verifying static-library libruby-static.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:217: recipe for target 'libruby-static.a' failed
make: *** [libruby-static.a] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
transdb.h unchanged
```

Have any of you managed to install and run the CI runner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to install an unofficial runner.

Guide here:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-manually.md

You need to have an account and be signed in in order to be able to read the guide.

Comment: the link is unreachable

Comment: There is an official guide available: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html